# load data infile partially cuts phone numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql

I made a table which name is 'test' in mysql in my PC like belows.

```
create table test(
telnum varchar(20) not null,
reg_date datetime not null default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
remarks text,
primary key(telnum)
);
```

And I uploaded a file named 1.txt into table 'test'.
1.txt's contents are like belows :

```
01011112222 

01022223333 

01033334444
```

And 'load data infile' syntax are like belows :

```
load data infile "c:/temp/1.txt"
ignore into table test;
```

But there is a problem.

Every phone numbers were cut like below.

```
Query OK, 3 rows affected, 3 warnings (0.00 sec) 
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 3 

mysql> select * from test; 

+-------------+---------------------+---------+ 
| telnum      | reg_date            | remarks | 
+-------------+---------------------+---------+ 

      |12222 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 
      |23333 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 
      |34444 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 
+-------------+---------------------+---------+ 
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Only 5 characters are remained from 11 characters.
6 characters disappeared.

And second problem is 'warnings'. Reason of warnings is like below.

```
mysql> show warnings; 
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------+ 
| Level   | Code | Message                                           | 
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------+ 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'reg_date' at row 1 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'reg_date' at row 2 | 
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'reg_date' at row 3 | 
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------+ 

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I did'nt put anything into the reg_date field.
But the  message says out of range value for column 'reg_date'.

What are the reasons and how can I solve these problems?

Comment: The question being long adds a little confusion, can you create a sqlfiddle example

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the line delimiter. On Windows it's usually `\r\n` rather then `\n` which is default if you omit `LINES TERMINATED BY` clause

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE "/tmp/1.txt"
IGNORE INTO TABLE test
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: @user2714872 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?